# LNK1104: cannot open file 'wxbase28d.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile existing project created using wxWidgets library.
I successfully compiled wxWidgets 2.8.12 library.
Now, I am trying to compile my project.
But I get error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'wxbase28d.lib'
```

---

Afterwards I added some variables in settings like:

**C/C++->Preprocessor Definitions:**

```
WIN32;__WXMSW__;_WINDOWS;_DEBUG;__WXDEBUG__;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

**VC++ Directories->Include Directories:**

```
D:\instantclient_12_1\sdk\include;$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib\mswd;$(WXWIN)\include;$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;
```

**Linker->General->Additional Library Directories:**

```
$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib;E:\app\vasyl\product\11.1.0\db_1\OCI\lib\MSVC\vc71;$(WXDIR284)\lib\vc_lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

**Resources->General->Additional Include directories:**

```
$(WXWIN)\include;c:\wxMSW284\include;$(WXDIR284)\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

Now, the situation is like this:

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgfree.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrealloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memmove.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _tolower already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(tolower.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isalpha already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isdigit already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _isspace already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(_ctype.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strtoul already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: __strtoi64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: __strtoui64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: __errno already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: __vsprintf_p already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(vsnprnc.obj)
...
...
etc.
```

Can someone help me spot what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using different CRT settings (static vs DLL) for your project and the library. Make sure to (re)build both of them using the same option, either `/MD[d]` or `/MT[d]`.

Comment: Either do that or change the way your library is built.  You could change the library to /Md[d].  The problem is that it is then highly dependant upon the MSVCR100 DLL.  If you try running your executable on another machine, the MSVCR100 DLL must be installed first.

Comment: Yes, if you use CRT DLLs you must insure they're installed on the target machine. But this is a wholly separate (and probably already answered elsewhere) question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which errors do you mean. If you build everything (i.e. *both* wxWidgets *and* your application) using `/MT[d]` you shouldn't have any errors. You do need to rebuild wxWidgets, did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes for this linker error. First adress to check is MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx

What is `$(WXWIN)` and how does it differ from `$(WXDIR284)`? It seems, you include wxWidgets path twice...